# Something confusing in Linux boot mem initialization

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am a newbie of Linux kernel learning. Now I am reading the Linux kernel codes with an old version of 2.4. From the books, I know that a provisional page_table was activated in bootstrap, which mapped the both PAGE_OFFSET ~ PAGE_OFFSET + 8M and 0 ~ 8M to physical 0 ~ 8M. But in function init_bootmem_core, you can see the codes:

```
bootmem_data_t *bdata = pgdat->bdata;
unsigned long mapsize = ((end - start)+7)/8;

pgdat->node_next = pgdat_list;
pgdat_list = pgdat;

mapsize = (mapsize + (sizeof(long) - 1UL)) & ~(sizeof(long) - 1UL);
bdata->node_bootmem_map = phys_to_virt(mapstart << PAGE_SHIFT);
bdata->node_boot_start = (start << PAGE_SHIFT);
bdata->node_low_pfn = end;

/*
 * Initially all pages are reserved - setup_arch() has to
 * register free RAM areas explicitly.
 */
memset(bdata->node_bootmem_map, 0xff, mapsize);

return mapsize;
```

the mapstart is equal to the first page number after kernel, and it wasn't mapped in the provisional page_table, how can use "memset(bdata->node_bootmem_map, 0xff, mapsize);" in the penultimate line?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super familiar with the 2.4 boot process, but the page tables may be initialized at this time, but has the kernel actually been transitioned to protected mode yet? Until that happens (at least on Intel architectures), you're in x86 Real Mode where you're directly addressing physical frames.

Comment: Thank you, Paul. But at this time the paging has already be enabled, I just think that the virtual address [node_bootmem_map, node_bootmem_map + mapsize] has not been addressed yet.